# How could i use let's encrypt behind a django application without stopping the server?

Tags: django, lets-encrypt

I have a django application running on a server. I want to use let's encrypt to provide an encrypted connection. I could use the standalone option of their ACME client, but i don't want to stop my server, what i would have to do.

So there is the webroot option, that work with my allready running webserver (nginx). Django would process the request in this case. My question is, how should it look like on the django side to get this running (keeping automated renewal several months in mind)?

Comment: You should be able to configure your web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) to serve the required files.

Comment: Do you have any idea, how nginx could do that? In my case nginx forwards the request to my gunicorn socket.

Comment: Add a location block so that Nginx serves the required files, instead of forwarding the request to gunicorn. The guide that Matthew linked to has instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what setup others use, but I generally set up Django apps with Nginx serving static content and Gunicorn as the application server. It's widely accepted that Django apps usually use this kind of two web server setup. The standard instructions for setting up Let's Encrypt with Nginx worked fine for me.

Or Digital Ocean have an excellent [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) too.

EDIT: It looks like Nginx can do a "graceful" reload that just updates the config with no downtime. For Debian or Ubuntu pre Systemd this would be `sudo service nginx reload`, while for a distro with Systemd the command is `sudo systemctl reload nginx.service`.

Comment: I use nginx and gunicorn. I know the guide and used it once. But using the standalone option, would require me to stop my running application. I edited my question a little bit. Hopefully it is better to understand now.

Comment: I used the webroot plugin as described in the guide. Works fine for me.

Comment: But then i would have to stop my running webserver. I want to mitigate this.

Comment: There's no getting away from the need to restart Nginx unless you have multiple servers and load balancing, or already have something like Varnish in front of Nginx. A second or two of downtime due to restarting Nginx is not a big issue for most web apps.

Comment: All you need to be able to do with the webroot plugin is add a route to Nginx to serve up that file. For that you have to restart Nginx. If you have load balancing or something like Varnish in front of Nginx then that can continue serving while you restart Nginx. Otherwise it's tough luck.

Comment: well couldn't i use  the certonly command and modify my django app to serve the files?

Comment: Django isn't really set up for serving static files. Is it really that much of an issue if Nginx is down for a couple of seconds? If you absolutely need 100% uptime I'd think you'd normally already have load balancing in place.

Comment: Also you'd just have to restart the application server instead of Nginx so your application would still be down for a second or two.

Comment: The thing is, that i host several applications on different virtual domains. If it wouldn't be a problem, i could just proceed as usual.

Comment: Are any of these things where a couple of seconds of downtime will be an issue? If there's more than one on the same server then it sounds unlikely since at the very least an app like that would not be sharing a VPS. I really doubt that the couple of seconds required to restart Nginx will cause any hardship. I'd also point out that Nginx will be restarted anyway when the package manager next upgrades it, so you can't guarantee it will remain running in perpetuity.

Comment: Apparently Nginx can do a graceful reload with no downtime - have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**In case other users come this way like I did from Google, here's how I improved this situation:**

I was unsatisfied by my options when it came to creating `ACME` challenges for Let's Encrypt when running a `Django` application. [So, I rolled my own solution and created a Django app!](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-letsencrypt) Basically, you can manage your `ACME` challenges as just another object, and the app will produce the proper end-point URL.

Yes you are installing an app which means a deploy / update to your app, but once you've done that managing your challenges is far easier in the long run.

Simply [`pip install django-letsencrypt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-letsencrypt) and follow the [`README`](https://github.com/urda/django-letsencrypt/blob/release/README.rst) to be on your way.

Comment: Hi, I tried your project, but few questions happened. How to set "ACME Request" and response? Is there any demo or example? The requests seems shouldn't be static object, right?

Comment: Hi @TonyWang ! Please checkout the example project, and use `GitHub` issues if you **really** think you have found a bug. But the simple app and README should get you far enough. Example project: https://github.com/urda/django-letsencrypt/tree/v2.0.0/example_project